# Python - how to access file downloaded from S3 to reupload

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

Trying to download from an S3 via a python lambda and then re-upload the file to a different folder (I don't want to just use a client to move folder i actually want to download and re-upload)

```
    #Download object to the file    
    obj = s3_resource.Bucket('my-bucket').download_file('test-large-file-transfer-base/testnote.pdf', '/tmp/testnote.pdf')
    s3_resource.Bucket('my-bucket').upload_file(obj, 'test-large-file-transfer-target/')
```

The above code results in the error

`"errorMessage": "Filename must be a string",`

Answer (score 1):

First argument to [upload_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.upload_file) should be `string`, but in your case it is some object `obj`.

So, to upload `/tmp/testnote.pdf` to `my-bucket` it should be (you also need to modify `key`):

```
s3_resource.Bucket('my-bucket').upload_file('/tmp/testnote.pdf', 'test-large-file-transfer-target/testnote.pdf')
```